# Bash script to manipulate two decimal numbers in a line

Tags: bash, numbers, decimal

Two of the lines of data that I am processing look like this.

```
18 xy Pqr  -3879.65 xp9  a-kxp   Kap 97868.08 P8A jrh-uyjf iu-re
A4-18 usU Aqr 974.59  xpab9  Tb7k-p   ptx 1533.93  K-doe Uap-qe1
```

Main characteristics:

- Every line has two decimal numbers.
- The first number can be positive or negative but the second number is always positive.

I want to flip the sign of the first number (positive to negative and
vice versa) and delete the second number.

With limited skills in bash, I wrote the following script in a brute
force method. It looks so inelegant!  Thank you for any pointers the
forum members could possibly provide to make it better.

```
#replace whitespaces with "_" for easy 'sed'-ing
a=`echo "$this_line" | sed -e "s/ /_/g"`

#get head part with first decimal number
b=`echo $a | grep -Po '^.*?[-]?[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+'`

#pick the decimal number from the head part
c=`echo $b | grep -Po '[-]?[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+'`

#flip the sign of the decimal number from the head part
d=`echo -1 \* $c | bc -l`

#delete decimail number from the head part
e=`echo "$b" | sed -e "s/$c$//"`

#put back head part with the decimal number sign flipped
f=`echo $e$d`

#get tail part with second decimal number
g=`echo "$a" | sed -e "s/^$b//"`

#pick the decimal number from the tail part
h=`echo $g | grep -Po '^.*?[-]?[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+'`

#delete decimail number from the tail part
i=`echo "$g" | sed -e "s/^$h//"`

#join back without second decimal number and first decimal sign flipped
j=`echo $f"  "$i`

#replace back "_" by whitespace
modified_line=`echo "$j" | sed -e "s/_/ /g"`
```

Comment: Intention is not to delete characters between the two numbers. They are not in fourth or eighth positions; their positions can vary form string to string.

Comment: In virtually any programming language, I would first split the line by whitespace, so that you have an array of items. Then loop over the array, and test whether the element looks like a number. If it is, do the operation (line change or replace the element by an empty value). Finally recreate the string based on the modified array. The drawback (if you do this naively in bash) is that multiple spaces will end up squeezed together into a single space. You **can** avoid this in bash too, but it becomes a bit complicated. Better switch to a more suitable language.

Comment: Is there any simple command to split the line by the decimal numbers?  In that case I will have five parts: a) part before first decimal number, b) first decimal number, c) part between two decimal numbers, d) second decimal number, and e) part after second decimal number.

Comment: You can use regular expressions to tear a string apart. In the bash man page, section "compund commands", look up the part where it explains about _[[ expression ]]_. This also explains the use of regular expressions for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you. So much to learn!

Comment: Finally I manged to split each line into five tokens by using sed's  back-reference. This is what I mentioned above but took two days to figure it out. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like

```
awk '
{
    flipped=0
    for (i=1; i< NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /-*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) {
            $i = (!flipped++) ? -$i : "";
        }
    }
    print
}
'
```

which produces

```
18 xy Pqr 3879.65 xp9 a-kxp Kap  P8A jrh-uyjf iu-re
A4-18 usU Aqr -974.59 xpab9 Tb7k-p ptx  K-doe Uap-qe1
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I can modify it to adapt to the real data. At present, it prints let say 5.00 as 5. I am new to awk. Is there a sed/grep solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Awk is a much better tool when dealing with floating-point numbers, because Bash does not have a float type:

```sh
awk '{ printf ("%s %s %s %f %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, -$4, $5, $6, $7, $9, $10) }' input_file
```

Comment: This will work if the numbers are at fixed positions such as at 4th and 8th.  Unfortunately, I am dealing with numbers that can appear are in different positions.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
str="18 xy Pqr  -3879.65 xp9  a-kxp   Kap 97868.08 P8A jrh-uyjf iu-re"
echo "$str" \
  | grep -Eo -- '-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+' \
  | head -n 1 \
  | awk '{print ($1 * -1)}'
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -Eo -- '-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+''` Will find any string that starts with optionally a hyphen *followed by* digits *followed by* a period *followed by* digits
- `head -n 1`  will then retrieve only the **First** result from the grep
- `awk '{print ($1 *- 1)}` will then print the first number times `-1` (thereby flipping the sign)

#### oneliner

```sh
echo "$str" | grep -Eo -- '-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+' | head -n 1 | awk '{print ($1 * -1)}'
```

Comment: This code produces the first decimal number sign flipped which is good. However, it does not print other parts of the string with second decimal number removed.  Is there any way to print the non-matched parts of the string?

Comment: What the purpose of double dash after -Eo in the code? Without them the code does not run.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and more readable solution using awk and variable substitution

```
#get the string
string="A4-18 usU Aqr 974.59  xpab9  Tb7k-p   ptx 1533.93  K-doe Uap-qe1"
#get the first number
firstNumber=$(echo $string | awk '{print $4}')
#get the second number
secondNumber=$(echo $string | awk '{print $8}')
#calculate absolute value
absoluteValue=${firstNumber#-}
#replace string
echo $string | sed s/$firstNumber/$absoluteValue/ | sed s/$secondNumber//
```

Comment: In my data the decimal numbers are not always at 4th and 8th locations. So it will not work in general.

Answer (score 0):

#!/bin/bash

msg="18 xy Pqr K  -261.90 xp9 P a-kxp  7873.57  Kap  P8A  jrh-uyjf"

printf '%s\n' "$msg"

#to preserve whitespaces, replace them with "_"

a=`echo "$msg" | sed -e "s/ /_/g"`

#display the string to show breaking points

b=`echo $a | sed -n "s/\(^.*\.[0-9].*_\)\([0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\)\(.*$\)/\1|\2|\3/p"`

echo $b

#delete the second decimal number

b=`echo $a | sed -n "s/\(^.*\.[0-9].*_\)\([0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\)\(.*$\)/\1 \3/p"`

#echo $b

#pick the only decimal number present in the remaining string

c=`echo $b | grep -Po '[-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'`

#change sign of the decinal number

d=`echo -1 \* $c | bc -l`

#substitute the decinal number back to the string with new sign

e=`echo ${b/$c/$d}`

#replace back "_" by whitespace

modified_line=`echo "$e" | sed -e "s/_/ /g"`

printf '%s\n' "$modified_line"

exit 0

Comment: I learned a lot while doing the above. I never knew that sed can be so powerful!